# How do you unit test a MVC controller with EF SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

Below is a controller with a Post Method. How do i write a unit-test against the CREATE method without saving the changes to the database?

I am trying to write test against my controllers so that when other developers change the code it will not break my functionality ( i have a little bit of functionality on the Create method to keep it simple for now).

```
public class AdministratorController : Controller
{
  private IUnitOfWork _uow;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    ViewBag.id = model.Id;

    if (model.FirstName == model.LastName)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot have same first name and last name.");
    }


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MyClass record = new MyClass();

        record.SAFirstName = model.FirstName;
        record.SALastName = model.LastName;
        record.SATitle = model.Title;
        record.SAEmail = model.EmailAddress;

        record.Since = DateTime.Now;

        _uow.AdministratorRepository.AddRecord(record);
        _uow.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

}

2.) my UOW looks something like this:

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MasterContext _context;

```
public UnitOfWork(MasterContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public UnitOfWork()
{
    _context = new MasterContext();
}

public void SaveChanges()
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

private IAdministratorRepository _Repo;

public IAdministratorRepository AdministratorRepository
{
    get
    {
        if (this._Repo == null)
        {
            this._Repo = new IAdministratorRepository(_context);
        }
        return _Repo;
    }
```

}

3) And my AdministratorRepository constructor looks like:

```
    private readonly MasterContext _context;

    public AdministratorRepository(MasterContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: The classic answer is, you don't. You abstract out anything like the database. However, my new thinking is that you use either SQL CE or SQL Server LocalDB to create a database that is scooped to your test life cycle.

Comment: You've already done the hard work, by abstracting your database access behind a mockable interface.  Just create a stub that simulates the action you want, or use a mocking framework.  If you have any methods that pass Linq directly, you will have some issues as Linq to Entities behaves slightly different from Linq to Objects, which is what most mocking frameworks would use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to inject a fake/mock IUnitOfWork into your controller. The simplest way to do that is to create an internal constructor on the controller that takes the fake object and create a property that either creates a new instance or returns the existing one.

```
private IUnitOfWork _uow;
private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork
{
    get
    {
        _uow = _uow ?? new UnitOfWork();
        return _uow;
    }
}

public AdministratorController() {}

internal AdministratorController( IUnitOfWork uow )
{
    _uow = uow;
}
```

You'll also need to modify the AssemblyInfo file for the MVC project to make the internal constructor visible to the unit test project. Look up the InternalsVisibleToAttribute for that.

Now in the unit test you can create your fake/mock object and inject it. You don't indicate what mocking framework you're using. We use FakeItEasy, so it would be something like:

```
var uow = A.Fake<IUnitOfWork>();

var controller = new AdministratorController( uow );

A.CallTo( () => uow.SaveChanges() ).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: Then you'll have to adjust the above code to use MOCK to create your mock/fake/stub IUnitOfWork. Personally I've never heard of MOCK so I'm not going to be of much help in the specifics, but honestly at this point you should be able to take it from here and figure out the details of creating a mock object yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should mock your dependencies.In your example AddRecord() of your repository.And after that you should test the returning model fields with your expected model(that you have to set in your unit testing method).